# Generating a single unit test for a function inside of a controller Symfony2/PHP

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony

I have a function that exists within a controller. 
I want to that the logic is sound by writing a small unit test with assertions to match correctly with the output of the function.

I've created a new unit folder to house all the little unit tests for the controller. The correct term may be a functional test?

This is the current set up I have to house all of the assertions for the function. My question is, out of all the functions that exist in this external controller, how can I bring that function in and perform a test on the logic within it?

```
<?php


namespace Acme\SimplewanBundle\Tests\Unit;

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool;

class ConfigControllerUnitTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {


    public function testValidIpRange() {





    }

}
```

Comment: can you post the code of the method you want to test?

Comment: I don't think it makes much of a sense to unit test controllers. Move your logic into separate classes instead. If you really want to test controllers, use behat for functional tests.

Answer (score 1):

First, the method should probably be moved to a service independent from the controller. In any case, without doing that change, you can already test the controller class as any other PHP class:

```
namespace Acme\SimplewanBundle\Tests\Unit;

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool;

class ConfigControllerUnitTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testValidIpRange()
    {
        $controller = new \AppBundle\Controller\ConfigController();
        $this->assertTrue($controller->isValidIpRange(...));
    }
}
```